# transfer cpanel data from one host to another

Tags: cpanel

I'm having bad luck (or just my lack of proper due diligence) with web hosts.  I am going to again move to a new server but want to make sure I don't make the same mistake twice.  Last time I had a tough time preserving my emails.

What is the simplest way to bundle up the data in my cpanel, primarily **email** and **cron jobs**.  I'm not worried about the website itself, I have backups and can easily re-load that.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can make a backup through the Cpanel, just make sure it is a 'full backup' instead of a partial backup through the backup wizard.

After you uploaded the backup file to the new server, you may restore files through WHM. Your emails and cron jobs will be recovered also.

You may check out this [link](http://www.nineteenlabs.com/2007/12/09/how-to-transfer-cpanel-accounts-from-one-server-to-another-cpanel/) for step by step instructions.

Answer (score 0):

If you are having root access to the server, Please follow these steps.

From cpanel interface

> Backups >> Generate/Download a Full Backup >> download backup file

from destination server, get into whm

> Main >> Backup >> Restore a Full Backup/cpmove file

Make sure that the cpmove backup file is placed at the /home of the new server.